# How to Print Out the Words In a Trie With a Vector Given a Particular Prefix

Tags: c++, vector, insert, trie

I am currently working on a project in which I need to print out the words in a trie that match a given prefix, given by a user using a string vector to print out the words. However, I am having trouble getting started with this, and would love any suggestions that you guys could give me.

This is an example of what I mean

Words in trie { app, address, add, beg, cow, mice}
prefix given ad
using a vector to print out words that contain the prefix ad:
address
add

Thank you very much for any help that you provide.

Comment: I say this depends on how you implemented your trie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, a trie is a tree.

In a trie, all words with a given prefix (say `ad`) are actually stored in the subtree of your trie that is accessed when searching for the prefix `ad`.
So to print all words in your trie that have a given prefix is done in 2 steps:

1. Find the node `node` corresponding to your prefix
2. List all the word in the subtree rooted in `node`.

Here is a pseudocode:

```
find_all_words_starting_with(string prefix, trieNode node, int depth){
    if (depth == length(prefix)){
        suffix = empty_string
        print_all_words_with_prefix(prefix, suffix, node)
    } else {
        letter = prefix[depth]
        if (node.hasChild(letter)){
            find_all_words_starting_with(prefix, node.getChild(letter), depth+1)
        } else { // no word with the correct prefix
            return
        }
    }
}

print_all_words_with_prefix(prefix, suffix, node){
    if (node.isCompleteWord){
        print(prefix + suffix)
    }
    for each letter c in the alphabet {
        if (node.hasChild(c)){
            print_all_words_with_prefix(prefix, suffix + c, node.getChild(c))
        }
    }
}
```

`find_all_words_starting_with` does the first part of the job. It find the node corresponding to the prefix, and calls the second function, `print_all_words_with_prefix`, that will print all the complete words in the subtree.

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on the implementation of the trie, although I provide an example trie below.

Each trie contains three things:

- A bunch of branches
- A root (may be null)
- a bool that says whether or not this trie represents a complete word

Based on this, we can do things like add words to the trie, check if a word is in the trie, and apply a function over all the words in the trie. I provide member functions to do each of those things.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>

struct WordTrie {
    static int index_from_char(char c) {
        return (unsigned char)c; 
    }
    static int char_from_index(int index) {
        return (char)(unsigned char)index; 
    }
    std::unique_ptr<WordTrie[]> branches; 
    WordTrie* root; 
    bool is_complete_word = false; 
    // Make an empty Trie
    WordTrie() : branches(nullptr), root(nullptr) {}
    // Make a WordTrie with the given root
    WordTrie(WordTrie* root) : branches(nullptr), root(root) {}


    int get_index_in_root() const {
        WordTrie const* branch_zero = root->branches.get();
        return std::distance(branch_zero, this); 
    }
    void append_char(std::string& s) {
        if(root != nullptr) {
            s += char_from_index(get_index_in_root()); 
        }
    }
    void add_word(char const* str, int length) {
        if(length > 0) {
            char c = *str; 
            if(branches == nullptr) {
                branches.reset(new WordTrie[256]); 
                for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                    branches[i].root = this; 
                }
            }
            branches[index_from_char(c)].add_word(str + 1, length - 1); 
        } else {
            is_complete_word = true; 
        }
    }
    bool has_word(char const* str, int length) {
        if(length == 0) {
            return is_complete_word; 
        }
        return branches[index_from_char(*str)].has_word(str + 1, length - 1); 
    }
    bool has_word(std::string const& s) {
        return has_word(s.data(), s.size()); 
    }
    template<class F>
    void apply_over_words_in_trie(std::string const& word, F&& func) {
        if(is_complete_word) {
            func(word); 
        }

        // Exit if there are no branches
        if(branches == nullptr) return; 
        //Add character to 'word'
        std::string new_word = word + '_';
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            new_word.back() = char_from_index(i); 
            branches[i].apply_over_words_in_trie(new_word, func); 
        }
    }
};
```